# Intellij java package does not exist (JDA)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, discord-jda

So I recently came back to a old java project which had broken due to an outdated Java discord API [(JDA)](https://github.com/discord-jda/JDA) version. Upon updating the dependency tag to the latest version in maven and rebuilding, I have been getting [package x does not exist errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3PXb.png).

I have tried reloading the project from maven, downloading sources, invalidating caches and rebuilding, none seem to fix the issue. I don't understand why this would be, as I have only changed the version of JDA. The packages [still exist in the new version.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWbqx.png)
Here are the relevant parts of my pom file.

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>dv8tion</id>
            <name>m2-dv8tion</name>
            <url>https://m2.dv8tion.net/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-beta.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm not very well versed in Java this was a side project for me, but any help would be very much appreciated. I'm sure I must be overlooking something obvious.

Comment: It is better if you can paste the error and the directory structure in the question itself. However, the error says the package `net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.channel` does not exists. Could you check specifically for that particular package. It is not visible whether that package is present or not in in your screenshot.

Comment: If the project is publicly available a link to the sources would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was actually really bothering me, so I stayed up quite late and tried one last solution before going to bed. I had to go to `File` > `Project Structure` and remove all the modules using the `delete (-)` button. Then I had to re-add the project as a maven project by right clicking the pom file and selecting `add as maven project`and rebuilding. This seemed to fix the problem. Why it worked when nothing else did, I am not quite sure.